# intermittent error while calling GMAIL API - "The caller does not have permission"

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, oauth2-playground

getting this error intermittently

> HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest returned "The caller does not have permission"

It works sometimes and other times it doesn't. I see the same issue on the oauth2 playground

this is my code -

```
googlecredentials = GoogleCredentials(
    access_token=None,
    client_id='xxx',
    client_secret='xxxx',
    refresh_token='xxxx',
    token_expiry=None,
    token_uri="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token", 
    user_agent='Python client library'
)

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=googlecredentials)

results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
labels = results.get('labels', [])
response = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='subject:FDA').execute()
print(response)
```

Comment: I could see a refresh token. Is it possible you may sometime use an expired token, as you said it worked sometime?

Comment: I hard refreshed my browser - `ctrl+F5`  . It worked

Comment: Hi ! Does it happen exclusively in your account and in which rate would you say is this happenning? Also, does it still occur in the OAuth2 playground after refreshing the page? There is a similar reported behaviour filed as a bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160441983), check it out to see if your case is similar or identical to it and if so add a +1 to indicate you are experiencing the same behaviour.

Comment: Hi ! The [bug that was reported](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160441983) has  been fixed already, are you still experiencing the same issue or did this fix also solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue came very recently. I have been using GMAIL API for more than a year now and I have never faced this issue. I don't know if there is an issue from our side or Gmail changed their policy of usage. But, regardless I did manage to find the solution for it. The main issue that I was having was my creds (google credentials in your case) was getting expired and each time it was expired I had to refresh them. So, a simple solution would be to just refresh them.

```
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
```

My native language is python so I have written the code in the same language but you can head over [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) and see something similar in your native language

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing this all of a sudden.
Everything was working fine for many months nothing changed in the code.
Also seeing the token is getting refreshed.

-rw-r--r--  1 kosalanbalarajah staff  728 Jul  6 12:50 token.pickle

But the error does not get resolved.

Also has the refresh code since the begining.

## If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.

```
    # If token.pickle does not exist there are no valid token, let user log in again to generate token and save the token for furture use.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(credentialspath, self.SCOPES) # Change credentials.json to credentialspath
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(tokenpath, 'wb') as token: # Change token.pickle to tokenpath
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    return creds
```